# Quadratic character of factorials

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and $S_p=\{(n!)^2 \bmod p, n=1,2,\dotsc,p-1\}$ the set of residues mod $p$ of squares of factorials. This set is obviously a subset of the group of quadratic residues mod p. For $p=3,5,7,13,17,23,29$ it is also a group for multiplication mod $p$, i.e. a subgroup of the group of quadratic residues.

> Question: Are there infinitely many primes $p$ for which $S_p$ is a group modulo $p$?

Comment: I found "such primes" a bit difficult to parse, so I re-wrote to what I think you meant.  Please feel free to change or revert if I got it wrong.

Comment: There are no primes $p$ between 54 and 2000 for which $\# S_p$ divides $p-1$, so my guess would be no.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch, would you define #$S_p$? — sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @WlodAA It's the cardinality of the set in the question. If the set is going to be a subgroup, its order better divide the order of the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In view of the identity $(n!)^2/((n-1)!)^2=n^2$, the set $S_p$ generates the subgroup $Q_p<\mathbb F_p^\times$ of quadratic residues; thus, if $S_p$ is a subgroup, then in fact $S_p=Q_p$. Clearly, a necessary and sufficient condition for this to happen is that the sequence of factorials $\{1!,\dotsc,(p-1)!\}$ hits at least one element out of each pair $(a,p-a)$, $1\le a\le (p-1)/2$.

The sequence $\{n!\}_{1\le n\le p-1}$ has been studied by a number of authors (see, for instance, [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01198) and those referenced therein), and is known to be surprisingly difficult. I therefore doubt anything definite can be proved in this direction.

Comment: The set  $ S_p$ satisfy (all operation are mod p) :                                                                              a. $1 \epsilon S_p$                                                                                                                b. $x\epsilon S_p \to x^{-1}\epsilon S_p$
c. $x,y\epsilon S_p$ and ${x}\neq{y} \to x\cdot{y}\epsilon S_p$                                        
 If $S_p$ is  a group,  we have to proove only that $x\epsilon S_p\to x^{2}\epsilon S_p$

Comment: @AndrejLeško: a) and b) are quite straightforward, but how do you prove c)? Anyway, if we believe that $S_p$ is "normally" not a subgroup, then (assuming c)) the implication $x\in S_p\ \Rightarrow\ x^2\in S_p$ is just wrong...

Comment: Correction of my comment: c. $S_p\subseteq S_p\cdot{S_p}$ where $S_p\cdot{S_p}=\lbrace x\cdot{y},x,y\epsilon S_p\rbrace$

Comment: Well, $S_p\subseteq S_p\cdot S_p$ just because $1\in S_p$, right?

Comment: Of course,it is trivial, I ment $S_p$ without $1$. It is interesting that all groups $S_p,p<54$ are of the form $\{\pm2^n\}$ or $\{\pm4^n\}$. Why?